# Inserting data from excel file in MSACCESS database using JSP

Tags: jsp, ms-access-2007, netbeans-7

This code is running correctly for inserting data from excel file into MSACCESS table using "APACHE POI library", but it is not inserting the values.

The code is not showing any error but tt is printing "Not able to insert......." on running:

Here, I've used DSN to connect to MSACCESS Database.
NETBEANS IDE

DSN: amandsn
MS Office 2007 Access Table: Student
MS Office 2007 Excel file: "myexcel.xls" which consists of 3columns i.e Name, Grade and Subject and there data which I want to insert into a MSACCESS table.

```
    <%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <%@ page import ="java.util.Date" %>
    <%@ page import ="java.io.*" %>
    <%@ page import ="java.io.FileNotFoundException" %>
    <%@ page import ="java.io.IOException" %>
    <%@ page import ="java.util.Iterator" %>
    <%@ page import ="java.util.ArrayList" %>

    // Using Apache POI Libraries
    <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell" %>
    <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow" %>
    <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet" %>
    <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook" %>
    <%@ page import ="org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem" %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <%

   Connection con=null;
   Statement st =null;
   PreparedStatement ps=null;    


   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:amandsn");
   st=con.createStatement();


   %>  


   <%

   try {      
        String fileName="myexcel.xls";
        //Read an Excel File and Store in a ArrayList
        ArrayList dataHolder=readExcelFile(fileName);
        // Print the data read
        // PrintCellDataToConsole(dataHolder);

        String query="insert into Student values(?,?,?)";

        ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
        int count=0;
        ArrayList cellStoreArrayList=null;
        //For inserting into database
        for (int i=1;i < dataHolder.size(); i++) {
          cellStoreArrayList=(ArrayList)dataHolder.get(i);
          ps.setString(1,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(0)).toString());
          ps.setString(2,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).toString());
          ps.setString(3,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString());
          count= ps.executeUpdate();
          out.println(((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString() + "\t");
       }

//For checking data is inserted or not?
if(count>0)
   { %>
           Following details from Excel file have been inserted in student table of database
               <table>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Name</th>
                       <th>Grade</th>
                       <th>Subject</th>
                   </tr>

     <% for (int i=1;i < dataHolder.size(); i++) {
        cellStoreArrayList=(ArrayList)dataHolder.get(i);
     %>
        <tr>
           <td><%=((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(0)).toString() %></td>
           <td><%=((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).toString() %></td>
           <td><%=((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString() %></td>
        </tr>
     <%}
   }
else
   { %>
      <center> Not able to insert.......</center>

<% }
    }
    catch(Exception e1){e1.printStackTrace(); }

%>

    <%!

   public static ArrayList readExcelFile(String fileName)
   {
       /** --Define a ArrayList
           --Holds ArrayList Of Cells
       */
       ArrayList cellArrayLisstHolder = new ArrayList();

       try{
           /** Creating Input Stream**/
           FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);

           /** Create a POIFSFileSystem object**/
           POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

           /** Create a workbook using the File System**/
           HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

           /** Get the first sheet from workbook**/
           HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);           


           /** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
           Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
           while(rowIter.hasNext()){
              HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
              Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
              ArrayList cellStoreArrayList=new ArrayList();
              while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                 HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                 cellStoreArrayList.add(myCell);

           }
          cellArrayLisstHolder.add(cellStoreArrayList);
       }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
    return cellArrayLisstHolder;
    }%>   
   </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: show the complete stack trace

Answer (score 0):

```
count= ps.executeUpdate();
```

will always assign `count` to 0 and that is the reason why else part will get executed and displays `Not able to insert...`

Instead, wrap the above statement in `try-catch` as below and update the `count` value if insertion is successful

```
try {
     ps.executeUpdate();
     count++; 
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: I've done this now:  for (int i=1;i < dataHolder.size(); i++) {
              cellStoreArrayList=(ArrayList)dataHolder.get(i);
              ps.setString(1,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(0)).toString());
              ps.setString(2,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).toString());
              ps.setString(3,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString());
              
              try {
     ps.executeUpdate();
     count++; 
} catch(Exception e) {
}
              
              out.println(((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).toString() + "\t");
           }

Comment: outcome is the same @Mubin...not inserted

Comment: Before entering the for loop SOP the value of `dataHolder.size()` and check if it is greater than 1.

Comment: The value is 0, I did what you said to me...any suggestions now?

Comment: It means that your `readExcelFile(fileName)` method is not returning anything. Check out that method.

Comment: I've posted it above....public static ArrayList readExcelFile(String fileName)
   {
    //FULL CODE WRITTEN ABOVE   }%>

Comment: First try with an absolute path. Like copy it to `C:\Users\Amrita\` and then use 
`String fileName="C:\\Users\\Amrita\\myexcel.xls";`

Comment: No, I'm trying to insert data in horizontal form.. NAME GRADE SUBJECT...that is: john a maths aman b science jack d economics

Comment: Yes and No?? Didn't get you

Comment: sorry, that no was "Now" :)  Your suggestions worked correctly

Comment: Now, I'm trying to insert data in horizontal form..i.e example with 6columns... NAME GRADE SUBJECT...that is: john a maths aman b science